# ProcessPoolExecutor creating more than allowed maximum workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I have the following code to process a large CSV file. The function *processRecord* is a a cpu-intensive multi-threaded function that sends some HTTP requests and stores the collected results in a database. I want to be able to process a maximum of n=25 different records at the same time by spawning a new process for each row. However, I can not figure out why the number of created processes keeps increasing on and on, and not stopping at the allowed limit! Any help would be strongly appreciated. Thanks!

```
def processWebsites(largeCSV, chunksize= 10**3):

    nProcessWorkers = 25
    skipRows = 500
    iteration = 0
    exectuor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=nProcessWorkers)
    for chunk_df in pd.read_csv(largeCSV, chunksize=chunksize, usecols=[0, 1], header=None):
        print("started_chunk: %s -- %s"%((iteration-1)*chunksize, iteration*chunksize))
        for (index, row) in chunk_df.iterrows():
            if (iteration == 0) and (index<=skipRows): continue
            else:
                param = row[1]
                exectuor.submit(processRecord, (param))
        iteration = iteration + 1
```

Comment: How do you observe the number of processes growth?

Comment: by checking the 'ps aux | grep "python3 <filename.py>" | wc -l ' in terminal